# VsCode Java project Classpath output

Tags: java, github, visual-studio-code

I just cloned a java repository in Vscode, and rather than allowing me to put all my class files in the bin directory (default), it puts the class files in ApplicationSupport/Code/WorkspaceStorage, and it does not let me change it. Also, it defaults my source path to just one of the many folders in my repository, and does not let me compile or run code. Ive searched everywhere and I can't find any info on this topic. Does anyone know anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the classpath of your unmanaged folder(project without build tools) via the command `Java: Configure Classpath`.

See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-classpath-for-unmanaged-folders

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried what you suggested before multiple times, and each time I received the error "Cannot nest output folder inside output folder". However the new output folder in question was located no where near the original output folder. Do you know why this is happeing?

Comment: Would you mind to share a screenshot with your project folder structure and mark the folders you want to use as source/output?